# Different results after reduction

Tags: cuda, reduction

I've got two reduction algorithms, both are from [docs.nvidia](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf), so they should be correct but the first (very effective) gives me a wrong result. Second result is better but I expected better accuracy. Is there any error in algorithms or am I doing something in a bad way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "cuda_error.h"

//Lock definition
#ifndef __LOCK_H__
#define __LOCK_H__
struct Lock {
int *mutex;
Lock( void ) {
CudaSafeCall( cudaMalloc( (void**)&mutex,
sizeof(int) ) );
CudaSafeCall( cudaMemset( mutex, 0, sizeof(int) ) );
}
~Lock( void ) {
cudaFree( mutex );
}
__device__ void lock( void ) {
while( atomicCAS( mutex, 0, 1 ) != 0 );
}
__device__ void unlock( void ) {
atomicExch( mutex, 0 );
}
};
#endif
//-------------------------


const int N = 507904;
const int blockSize = 256;
int blocks = N/blockSize;

template <unsigned int blockSize>
__global__ void reduce(Lock lock, float *g_idata, float *g_odata, int n)
{
      extern __shared__ int sdata[];
      unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
      unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + tid;
      unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
      sdata[tid] = 0;

      while (i < n) 
      { 
          sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize]; 
          i += gridSize; 
      }

      __syncthreads();

      if (blockSize >= 512) { if (tid < 256) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 256]; } __syncthreads(); }
      if (blockSize >= 256) { if (tid < 128) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 128]; } __syncthreads(); }
      if (blockSize >= 128) { if (tid < 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; } __syncthreads(); }

      if (tid < 32) 
      {
          if (blockSize >= 64) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
          if (blockSize >= 32) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
          if (blockSize >= 16) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
          if (blockSize >= 8) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
          if (blockSize >= 4) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
          if (blockSize >= 2) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
      }

    if (tid == 0)
    {
        lock.lock();        
        *g_odata += sdata[0];
        lock.unlock();
    }

}

__global__ void reduction_sum(Lock lock,float *in, float *out, int N) 
{
    extern __shared__ float sf_data[];
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    sf_data[tid] = (i<N) ? in[i] : 0;

    __syncthreads();

    for (int s = blockDim.x/2; s>0; s>>=1) 
    {
      if (tid < s) 
        {
        sf_data[tid] += sf_data[tid + s];
      }
      __syncthreads();
    }

    if (tid == 0)
    {
        lock.lock();        
        *out += sf_data[0];
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
//initializing function
double los()
{
    return (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
}
//-------------------------------------------


int main (void)
{

//memory allocation 
    float *a;
    float *dev_a, *dev_blocksum1, *dev_blocksum2;
    float s1=0, s2=0, spr=0;

    a = (float*)malloc( N*sizeof(float) );
    CudaSafeCall( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, N*sizeof(float) ) );
    CudaSafeCall( cudaMemset( dev_a, 0, N*sizeof(float) ) );
    CudaSafeCall( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_blocksum1, sizeof(float) ) );
    CudaSafeCall( cudaMalloc(   (void**)&dev_blocksum2, sizeof(float)   )   );
    CudaSafeCall( cudaMemset( dev_blocksum1, 0, sizeof(float) ) );
    CudaSafeCall( cudaMemset( dev_blocksum2, 0, sizeof(float) ) );
//--------------------

//drawing, array fill
    srand(2403);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        a[i]=los();
        spr+=a[i];
    }
    printf("CPU sum: %f \n", spr);
//copy HtoD
    CudaSafeCall( cudaMemcpy( dev_a, a, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
//---------------------

Lock lock;

//reduce
    reduce<blockSize><<<blocks, blockSize, blockSize*sizeof(float)>>>(lock, dev_a, dev_blocksum1, N);
    CudaSafeCall(   cudaMemcpy ( &s1, dev_blocksum1, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost  )   );
    printf("GPU sum1: %f \n", s1);
//-----------------------

//reduction_sum
    reduction_sum<<<blocks, blockSize, blockSize*sizeof(float)>>>(lock, dev_a, dev_blocksum2, N);
    CudaSafeCall(   cudaMemcpy ( &s2, dev_blocksum2, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost  )   );
    printf("GPU sum2: %f \n", s2);
//---------------------

    return 0;
}

$ CPU sum: 253833.515625 
$ GPU sum1: 14021.000000 
$ GPU sum2: 253835.906250
```

Comment: Could you add the correct results ?

Comment: Never assume NVidia's code is always correct. It's not. That also extends to CUDA documentation, which to large parts in the early days was written by an intern and still haunts their website and the internet.

Comment: But furthermore, this might simply be a case of numerical stability.

Comment: Also, questions asking "why doesn't this work" should of course also refer to the input data; otherwise it'll be very hard to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: @fxm, I assume that CPU sum is correct result.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, in what way it depends on the input data? This case is very simple, there is N numbers in range 0 to 1 each.

Comment: @physicist: how do you think should one figure out what goes wrong where when you don't have the input data that leads to the error, including even N?! At this point, I'd just say, ignore the CUDA algorithm that gives you the worse result. Floating point arithmetic isn't exact.

Comment: Your error checking might be broken and depends on a file which you haven't shown.  When I run the code you have posted with `cuda-memcheck` it reports a variety of errors.  Also, the presentation link (dating from CUDA 1.1 timeframe!) is outdated.  An updated version of that presentation is [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).  I'm also puzzled why you would bother with the locking scheme when a simple `atomicAdd` should work and be faster.  I don't believe the locking scheme is in the presentation or derived from an NVIDIA suggestion?

Comment: @MarcusMüller  N is specified in the program, and the data is generated randomly.  I'm fully able to reproduce the indicated results with the posted code.  There is no lack of clarity around either the data or `N` in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things to mention.

1. I'm not sure your error checking is valid.  You haven't shown the file that implements this, and when I run your code with `cuda-memcheck`, I get various errors reported.  They all seem to be related to the lock function.
2. I'm not sure why you would use the lock function and I don't recommend it.  I don't think it is dropping out of scope when you think it is, based on the way you are using it.  I would suggest using `atomicAdd` instead, which should be faster and simpler.  At a minimum, comment out the `cudaFree()` statement in your destructor.
3. You are linking to an old presentation.  If you review a [newer version of it](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) then I think you will see that it is now recommending use of `volatile`.  I'm not going to rewrite your whole code for you, nor summarize that whitepaper again, but if you simply add `volatile` to the shared memory declaration for demonstration purposes, it will fix the resultant issue.
4. Your shared memory variable is declared as `int` but you are summing `float` quantities.  That won't work the way you want.  You could declare it like this instead:

   ```
   extern __shared__ volatile float sdata[];
   ```
5. The above changes get the code "working" for me.  The remaining item is the discrepancy between CPU and GPU results.  I believe this is due to floating-point order of operations not being the same on the CPU (serial reduction) vs. GPU (parallel reduction).  Since the discrepancy arises in the 6th significant digit on a `float` quantity, I would suggest this is well within the range of reasonableness for floating point results comparison.  If you desire more accuracy, you might try switching from `float` to `double`.  Also, there are various floating point papers you may wish to read that will help with understanding here, such as [this one](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html#comparison) and [this one](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your response, after reading the 4th section I feel ashamed but I couldn't find that mistake the whole day. I've taken that locking scheme from "CUDA by example".